# I am having trouble understanding part of an ExceptionError code

Tags: java

This is my first time posting a question so I apologize if I am vague or unclear. I'm still learning some of the essentials of Java and I came across a tutorial online regarding exceptions. The entire thing can be found here: [***Java World: Exceptions in Java***](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076700/core-java/exceptions-in-java.html).

This may be a dumb question but I'm having difficulty understanding it.

```
class VirtualCafe {
    public static void serveCustomer(VirtualPerson cust,
        CoffeeCup cup) {
        try {
            cust.drinkCoffee(cup);
            System.out.println("Coffee tastes just right.");
        }
        catch (UnusualTasteException e) {
            System.out.println(
                "Customer is complaining of an unusual taste.");
            String s = e.getMessage();
            if (s != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
            // Deal with an unhappy customer...
        }
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble understanding why would you want to store a string object and then have it print if the previous `println` seemed like it took care of the problem. What exactly does the second `println` print out? `drinkCoffee()` throws a few types of Exceptions including `UnusualTasteException`. I'd appreciate any feedback!

Here's the code for `UnusualTasteExpection`:

```
class UnusualTasteException extends Exception {
    UnusualTasteException() { }

    UnusualTasteException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your code (within drinkCoffee method) would be doing something like to throw an exception:

```
throw new UnusualTasteException ("Weird coffee taste!!!");
```

If you see Exception class's parent i.e. Throwable has a field called detailMessage and then when you call above constructor to throw an exception, it will set detailMessage field.

And that's what you are using in your second print statement. So your print statement would print "Weird coffee taste!!!"

By doing so, you get exact string and intention of exception. And you might be throwing same exception from tea, lemon etc. but if you were processing flow for coffee, you see that it was weird taste of coffee and not lemon or tea and so on.

Comment: did you mean getMessage() instead of detailMessage? and lastly, both statements are printed correct?

Comment: No so detailMessage is a field which getMessage returns. See [this](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Throwable.java.html) code for details.

Answer (score 1):

To give an example, if the exception is thrown like this:

```
throw new UnusualTasteException("The coffee is very bitter");
```

the `println()` you're asking about would print out `The coffee is very bitter`, which is more informative than the generic "unusual taste" message.

Answer (score 1):

This code (sort of) highlights a couple of things:

- Catching exceptions and getting meaningful information from them
- Dealing with `null` when it's undesirable to allow around

So, let's be explicit - the code in the catch block is dealing with whatever error message we bring back from the `drinkCoffee` method thrown by the `UnusualTasteException`.  That said, we print a more generic message about the fact that the customer had an unusual taste with their coffee.

The second `println` concerns if we had anything meaningful to learn from the exception; a message or a clue or something.  It could also be the case that someone passed in `null` to the constructor in this manner:

```
throw new UnusualTasteException((String) null);
```

...or more innocuously:

```
String msg = null;
throw new UnusualTasteException(msg);
```

If we don't have anything meaningful to print out, then we don't print it out.  We also want to avoid repeated calls to the method, so we store the result of the call into a variable.  This is what the second block accomplishes.

As a general aside, this is considered using [exceptions as flow control](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/189225/54997), because there are any number of ways to handle this scenario appropriately (an enum for satisfaction of taste, or a boolean for whether they liked it or not stored on the drinker).  In general, it's considered poor practice because exceptions are incredibly expensive to generate, and should be reserved for something truly *exceptional*.